# How to use Word2Vec CBOW in statistical algorithm?

Tags: nlp, logistic-regression, word2vec

I have seen few examples of using CBOW in Neural Networks models (although I did not understand it)

I know that Word2Vec is not similar to BOW or TFIDF, as there is no single value for CBOW

and all examples I saw were using Neural Network.

I have 2 questions

1- Can we convert the vector to a single value and put it in a dataframe so we can use it in Logistic Regression Model?

2- Is there any simple code for CBOW usage with logistic Regression?

More Explanation.

In my case, I have a corpus that I want to make a comparison between top features in BOW and CBOW

after converting to BOW

I get this dataset

```
RepID   Label   Cat   Dog   Snake   Rabbit  Apple Orange  ...
1       1       5     3     8       2       0 
2       0       1     0     0       6       9
3       1       4     1     5       1       7
```

after converting to TFIDF

I get this dataset

```
RepID   Label   Cat   Dog   Snake   Rabbit  Apple Orange  ...
1       1       0.38     0.42    0.02    0.22   0.00   0.19
2       0       0.75     0.20    0.08    0.12   0.37   0.21
3       1       0.17     0.84    0.88    0.11   0.07   0.44
```

I am observing the results of top 3 features in each model

so my dataset become like this

BOW (I put null here for the values that will be omitted)

```
RepID   Label    Cat   Dog   Snake   Rabbit  Apple Orange  ...
1       1        5      null    8    null   null   7
2       0        null   null    null    6   9   2
3       1        4      null    5    null   7   null
```

TFIDF (I put null here for the values that will be omitted)

```
RepID   Label   Cat   Dog   Snake   Rabbit  Apple Orange  ...
1       1       0.38     0.42    null    0.22   null   null
2       0       0.75     null    null    null   0.37   0.21
3       1       null     0.84    0.88    null   null   0.44
```

I want now to do the same with Word2Ven CBOW

I want to take the highest values in the CBOW model

```
RepID   Label  Cat   Dog   Snake   Rabbit  Apple Orange  ...
1       1      v11     v12    v13    v14   v15   v16
2       0      v21     v22    v23    v24   v25   v26
3       1      v31     v32    v33    v34   v35   v36
```

to be like this

```
RepID   Label    Cat   Dog   Snake   Rabbit  Apple Orange  ...
1       1        v11     null    v13    null   v15   null
2       0        null     null    v23    null   v25   v26
3       1        v31     null    v33    v34   null   null
```

Comment: Your data examples confusing because: (1) BoW & TFIDF vector models *don't* typically have 'null' values - there's an actual zero when term is missing; (2) it's unclear what the `v11`, `v23`, etc tokens are supposed to mean.; (3) never-mind 'CBOW' - there aren't really meaningful 'highest values' in a word2vec model: a word has an N-dimensional vector, where every dim is a different nonzero value, & any individual dim value has no independent meaning; (4) chosen words seem random unlike real data or natural language; (5) not clear what you're trying to predict/regress.

Comment: What is a real, tangible example of the kind of data you're starting with, and what is your real ultimate goal?

Comment: @gojomo i put null to illustrate that  i will delete values that are not in the top 3

Comment: @gojomo v11, v12, are represent Vector1 Venctor 2. etc.

Comment: But even when you delete lower values, a BoW or TFIDF or other vector-model still has a fixed-width feature representation, at the level that it becomes an input to a regression. What are  "Vector 1", "Vector 2", etc? Which **words** are they the vectors from, given that word2vec gives us a vector per word?

Comment: (For that matter, what's a 'RepID' supposed to be? What is being represented here, and what's the value you want to predict?)

Comment: I included the label now, it is just a binary 1 or 0 code. RepID is just an index

Comment: Thanks - but, it's still unclear what your `v23`/etc are. (For example would one document, like `RepID=2`, have a **different** word-vector for the word`snake` than another document? would have for the same word?)

Comment: @gojomo I want a method to identify the max vector in between 2 vestors ( this function I still do not know how to identify) so if we compare 100 vectors v1, v2, .. v100, then I asked for max 10 vectors i will get v24, v91, v36, v4... v19

Comment: What do you mean by "max vector"? (That's not usual terminology, and while one could pick the "vector with the largest magnitude", that's not usually very interesting in the context of word-vectors. The most common way of comparing word-vectors, cosine-distance, is totally oblivious to magnitude.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No matter the internal training method, CBOW or skip-gram, a word-vector is always a multidimensional vector: it contains many floating-point numbers.

So at one level, that is one "value" - where the "value" is a vector. But it's never a single number.

Word-vectors, even with all their dimensions, can absolutely serve as inputs for a downstream logistic regression task. But the exact particulars depend on exactly what data you're operating on, and what you intend to achieve - so you may want to expand your question, or ask a more specific followup, with more info about the specific data/task you're considering.

Note also: this is done more often with the pipeline of a library like `scikit-learn`. Putting dense high-dimensional word-vectors themselves (or other features derived from word-vectors) directly into "dataframes" is often a mistake, adding overhead & indirection compared to working with such large feature-vectors in their more compact/raw format of (say) `numpy` arrays.

Comment: I added more details. please let me know if it make sense what I am trying to acheive

Comment: Thanks for the extra details. Per comments above, your abstract/synthetic example data is still a bit confusing, and being more specific/concrete would help. (What's the real data, what's the real goal?) But most generally: it appears you have a binary text-classification problem. There are lots of ways to turn texts into feature-vectors. Some of those make use of word-vectors to help add features. But dropping word-vectors into individual dataframe cells is likely a wrong-turn.